# separating var app = new Vue({}); to another app.js

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a lot of vue that I used for every "samples".blade.php inside Resources/asset/js/**app.js**.

```
 var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
    var app = new Vue({});
```

However once i create a new ex. **app1.js** inside Resources/asset/js .What's inside of my new **app1.js** doesnt work. Even though i copy this:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');
```

still doesnt work.

I'm new using vue.js in laravel. I hope someone could explain to me how to proper use of vue.js. I just want to seperate this **var app**s. in another .js like the sample **app1.js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need to define different id for each app.

```
// frist page

// html
<div id="blog-app">
  {{ message }}
</div

// js
var blogApp = new Vue({
  el: '#blog-app', // <-this id
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Blog!'
  }
})



// second page

// html
<div id="gallery-app">
  {{ message }}
</div

// js
var galleryApp = new Vue({
  el: '#gallery-app', // <-this id
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Gallery!'
  }
})

// .. and so on
```

may be this can help to separate these apps.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: do i also need to create a new .js inside Resources/asset/js/ ?. sample that galleryApp.js?

Comment: then put it that. var galleryApp = new Vue({
  el: '#gallery-app', // <-this id
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Gallery!'
  }
})

Comment: what i want is to separate other var app because it loaded all of it. That's y i want to separate other var apps by creating new js. If that's the case that i need to name it "var app1 = new Vue({});" well i guess. i need to try it first then i rply later. Thanks for your help by the way.

Comment: I create appDeptHead.js then i copy this. require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Comment: but. This doesnt work. even i rename var appDeptHead

Comment: `separate other var app because it loaded all of it` hmm can you share more information about it,what is loads all of it ?